Python Recursion Incrementing
I am teaching my self python by working through a few books. I have been able to work through the examples and get the foundational understanding. However, python recursion is stumping me.
I have included the code below.  and in a screen shot. It seems to me that the first output would be
6 + 5 = 11, not 1 as is what the code prints as result. What is missing is the incrementor for k. I am assuming that the has an auto increment that starts at 0 and working up to 6
The question is, How is this code incrementing? I appreciate any guidance.
The printed results are:
1
3
6
10
15
21

def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

tri_recursion(6)


this may help you https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=display

k isn't incrementing, it's decrementing during each recursive call. The argument in the recursion is k-1.

Thank you very much for the support. Apologies for the delay in thanking you. I'm still trying to navigate the platform.
